# JQuery: Mouseover effect on dynamic list-element

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, mouseover, greedy

[image]

Static HTML at first

```
<div id="droppableZone">
      <!--Sortable List in the drop zone-->
      <ol class="nested_with_switch vertical"> 
         <li class="">
            <span class="icon-file4 ic-comp-default ic-elem "></span>
            <span comp-type="Webseite">Webseite Name</span>
            <div class="controls">
                 <span class="icon-pen ic-comp-blue"></span>
                 <span class="icon-x ic-comp-red"></span>
            </div>
            <ol></ol>
         </li>
       </ol>
 </div>
```

Dynamic HTML after drag&drop

```
<ol class="nested_with_switch vertical"> 
    <li class="">
            <span class="icon-file4 ic-comp-default ic-elem "></span>
            <span comp-type="Webseite">Webseite Name</span>
            <div class="controls">
                 <span class="icon-pen ic-comp-blue"></span>
                 <span class="icon-x ic-comp-red"></span>
            </div>
            <ol class="">
               <li class=""> ....
                <ol class="">
                   <li class="">
                     <ol></ol>
                   </li>
                </ol>
               </li>
             </ol>
      </li>
</ol>
```

Note: I removed repeating spans and divs for readability.

As you can see, there is an ordered-list (ol) in the left side. You can drag components from right and drop them into the ordered-list in the left. A website li-element has again an "ordered list" inside, so you can drop so many components as you want.

Then I have a hidden control-div with two icons inside the li-element. When you go over the li-element, the control-div will be visible. This is the JQuery-code.

```
$('#droppableZone ol').on('mouseover', 'li', function () {
    $(this).find('.controls').css('visibility', 'visible');
}).on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
    $(this).find('.controls').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

The problem is when I go a single li-element, all control-divs are visible. Could any help me to write the proper JQuery function for this feature?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post a fiddle or your html

Comment: @Harry I have posted my droppable zone html.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use CSS?

```
li .controls {
   display:none;
}
li:hover .controls {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: I have inside li-element again ol and li. So it won't help.

Comment: then you can use li>controls selector

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific about the .controls div. I don't know what the structure is but i would suggest being more accurate. something like:`$(this).closest(".controls")` or `$(this).parent(".controls")`

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter instead of mouseover:

```
$('#droppableZone ol').on('mouseenter', 'li', function () {
    $(this).find('.controls').css('visibility', 'visible');
}).on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
    $(this).find('.controls').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: @j809 no, you were doing with li so I said not work with hidden but using controls to hide and show obviously work.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem**

1. I suppose hidden elements **don't trigger mouseover** events.
2. Trying to `find` `.controls` in `ol` will give you all divs with class `.control`.

**Solution**

1. Set `opacity` instead of using `visibility`.
2. Also, select `children` for `li` instead and bind `mouseover` for those `li`.

So, your code will be like:

**JS**

```
$('#droppableZone ol li').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).children(".controls").css('opacity', '1.0');
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).children(".controls").css('opacity', '0.0');
});
```

Comment: Well I don't hide li-element. Inside li-element there is a div with a class name "controls". I hide only that div.